# Scaling a (beamer)poster output

Tags: scaling, beamerposter

I use beamerposter with pdfLateX. I normally make the poster for A0 page size but need to reduce the size of (scale) the poster to a specific width to fit a smaller size frame used for showing posters in our department. I realize I could design the poster for a smaller size but still I need to switch between size. So, is there a simple way to scale the entire poster with its content already when compiling it?

Comment: You may use `pdfpages`.

Comment: Why not just let the printer driver do the job to scale to whatever paper format you have?

Comment: True, Daniel! But, in some cases (services outside my control) the digital original has to be submitted to be printed in its final size directly.

Comment: @PeterJansson (Message is not related to the present question) When you review first posts, please check for appropriate retagging actions before stating "No action needed". (In the [latest](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/biblatex-nested-citations-with-the-textcites-command) question reviewed by you, the [tag:nesting] tag would have been useful.) Many thanks!

Comment: @lockstep (message relating only to the comment by lockstep) thanks for the comment and point well taken, however, I experience that the view of what and how things should be tagged differ so there will always be some discrepancies between users. Drop me a mail if you wish, see my profile text.

Comment: @PeterJansson Tagging discrepancies are inevitable to some degree, and reviewing does not (and should not) require comprehensive knowledge of existing tags. I pointed out the question at hand because it featured a link to a prior question, which in turn featured the [tag:nesting] tag. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep No worries, I just wanted to make sure I was not doing something wrong without knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posters are typically printed only once or twice, I would not bother too much about configuring the final page format in the LaTeX source. Instead just post-process the resulting PDF to fit the required paper format.

Many printing systems provide a "scale" or "auto-scale" option to fit some given content to the selected page size. If you have to to specify it manually, you give a scale factor of 1/√2 (0.707) to go down one [A paper format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#A_series).

If you actually do need a pdf of the requested size (because somebody else is going to print it), either "print to PDF" or employ the `pdfjam` utility:

```
pdfnup --no-landscape --scale 0.707 --paper a1 poster.pdf
```

will transform `poster.pdf` from A0 format into a file `poster-nup.pdf` in A1 format.

(The `pdfjam` utility actually does employ LaTeX with the `geometry` and `pdfpages` packages to do its job, so you can pass any options that are described in the `pdfpages` documentation.)