# Biblatex: nested citations with the \textcites command

Tags: biblatex, citing, nesting

I'd like to type a citation within the text and another citation inside the parenthesis for the year, something like this:

> The work of Author 1 (year; cited by Author 2, year)

For this, I've tried different options of the `\textcite` command but without results. Also I saw the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53923/25482), which works for multiple citations within parenthesis but not for in-text citations.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nested citation commands are not allowed, but one can simulate them (using the appropriate punctuation commands to ensure consistency with other citations):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

The work of \citeauthor{A01} \mkbibparens{\citeyear{A01}\postnotedelim cited by \cite{B02}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to post nearly the same answer. Just an addition: you can or course put this together into an own command like ``\mycite`` by ``\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\citeauthor{#1} \mkbibparens{\citeyear{#1}\postnotedelim cited by \cite{#2}}}``.

Comment: Please note, that `\citeyear` does not create a link to the bibliography. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: @SebastianWerk I don't know. Perhaps try a search for questions tagged with [tag:biblatex] and [tag:links] or [tag:hyperref].

Comment: With standard `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-like styles one can use `\cite*` instead of `\citeyear` to make things a bit more portable. (This will also create a link with the standard styles, while `\citeyear` does not, by default.)

Answer (score 5):

Citation commands generally can't (and shouldn't) be nested, but you can get around this rule with `\nocite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\newrobustcmd*{\postcite}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}\entrydata{#1}{\usebibmacro{cite}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcites(See)()[cited by \postcite{companion}]{knuth:ct:a}[10]{markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Data for the nested entry here isn't accessed until the second biber/BibTeX run. You can avoid additional biber runs by linking nested entries to their parents using cross references, entry sets or related entries.

Comment: While this mostly works for me, it gets a bit funky. with the usage `\autocite[\pno~XX (citing \postcite{work:yy})]{work:xx}` it comes out fine, but if I do `\autocite[\pno~XX (citing \postcite[YY]{work:yy})]{work:xx}` it gobbles basically all of the work:xx data, excluding the page number

Comment: specifically, the later ends up with `Work yy, p. XX , (citing YY.` (note that XX/YY are *page numbers*)