# Parencite "within" textcite

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I am using the biblatex-chicago package with the following options:

`\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}`

What I would like to have is a citation in the flow of text like the one that obtains from using `\textcite`, but with an extra citation in brackets right after the year of the first citation, just as if I were using the `\cite` command as an optional argument "within" the textcite command. I would like to have something like the following:

[image]

The closest I can get to this is by manually typing the first author's name and the opening bracket, use the `\citeyear` command with the first bibliographical entry and the `\cite` command with the second, and then manually type the closing bracket. However, that would put the original year (`origyear` in the `.bib` file) 1963 into round rather than square brackets. Besides, I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant solution.

Here is a MWEB that generates the round-bracket problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage,hidelinks,onehalfspacing]{book}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dray:laws_and_explanation_in_history,
author = {Dray, William H.},
title = {Laws and Explanation in History},
year = 1957,
location = {Oxford, UK},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}

@inbook{hempel:reasons_and_covering_laws_in_historical_explanation,
author = {Hempel, Carl G.},
title = {Reasons and Covering Laws in Historical Explanation},
subtitle = {Studies in Science, Explanation, and Rationality},
booktitle = {The Philosophy of Carl G. Hempel},
bookeditor = {Fetzer, James E.},
year = 2001,
origyear = 1963,
location = {New York},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
pages = {297--310},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Dray (\citeyear{dray:laws_and_explanation_in_history}, \cite{hempel:reasons_and_covering_laws_in_historical_explanation})
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.se.  It would be helpful if you could post a sample document and `.bib` entries that would illustrate the issue for people to play with. This seems especially necessary given that the Hempel entry has two dates. See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) for how to do that.

Comment: MWEB added in the original post.

Comment: @poxx I think this question is answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96736/98739 nested citations are not allowed, but your work-arount seems to work properly; you may want to change to `\citeauthor{dray} \parentext{\citeyear{dray}, \cite{hempel}}` to get the order of parentheses and brackets right.

Comment: This seems to work much better, except that it will remove the link to the bibliography from the first entry's year.

Comment: @LukasCB If you use `\citeauthor{dray} \parentext{\cite*{dray}, \cite{hempel}}` instead the link is there. I think you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @moewe added it as an answer. thanks for pointing out and giving the right clue.

Comment: Defining a new command for nested citations like the `\postcite` command provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/biblatex-nested-citations-with-the-textcites-command/96736#96736) worked for me. Thanks @LukasCB for pointing me to that discussion.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot do nested citations ([see also here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96736/98739)) there is only a work around:
I take your MWE (just changed `bibtex-keys`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    notitlepage,
    hidelinks,
    onehalfspacing]{book}
\usepackage[authordate,
    backend=biber,
    cmsdate=both,
    useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{dray,
        author = {Dray, William H.},
        title = {Laws and Explanation in History},
        year = 1957,
        location = {Oxford, UK},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    }

    @inbook{hempel,
        author = {Hempel, Carl G.},
        title = {Reasons and Covering Laws in Historical Explanation},
        subtitle = {Studies in Science, Explanation, and Rationality},
        booktitle = {The Philosophy of Carl G. Hempel},
        bookeditor = {Fetzer, James E.},
        year = 2001,
        origyear = 1963,
        location = {New York},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        pages = {297--310},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{dray} \parentext{\cite*{dray}, \cite[see e.g.][]{hempel}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

That is the result:

[image]