# How does one add a second name and year(s) within the parentheses produced by \textcite?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to use `\textcite` to produce something like:

> According to Stringer and Gamble (1993, p.159; *contra* Gargett 1989, 1999), the only clear example of an intentional Neanderthal burial is that of La Chapelle-aux-Saints 1 in Southwestern France.

I've looked around but couldn't find anything to that effect.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=2, doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{preset.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\begin{document}
According to \textcites[159]{Stringer1993}[contra][]{Gargett1989, Gargett1999}, the only clear example of an intentional Neanderthal burial is that of La Chapelle-aux-Saints 1 in Southwestern France.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which does not produce what I want:

[image]

EDIT: Here's what worked for me (both lines are identical, but for me only the second worked)

```
\citeauthor{Stringer1993}~\mkbibparens{\cite*[159]{String‌​er1993}; contra \cite{Gargett1989, Gargett1999}}
\citeauthor{Stringer1993}~\mkbibparens{\cite*[159]{Stringer1993}; contra \cite{Gargett1989, Gargett1999}}
```

Comment: Have a look at [What is the most elegant way to cite two things connected by a 'joining word' with biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213185/35864)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, maybe you want to show us an MWE so we can see what style you use and we have something to start from.

Comment: @moewe I think that's for citing in parentheses as in "Dragons exist. It is known (Smith 1993, contra Jackson 1999)", but I would like "Smith (1993, contra Jackson 1999) argues that it is known."

Comment: Mhh, one could probably come up with a solution similar to that from the answer I linked to, but that is really only worth it if you plan to use that more often than once. If you need that only rarely, I'd probably just fake it as in [Biblatex: nested citations with the \textcites command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96732/35864): `\citeauthor{Stringer1993}~\mkbibparens{\citeyear[159]{Stringer1993}; contra \cite{Gargett1989, Gargett1999}}` (you can of course stuff that into an ad-hoc command)

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to "faking it" like this, apart from the inline bulkiness?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit thick. You say `\citeyear` was not 'recognised', but then you say it worked for you? Faking the citation like this is of course a bit clumsy and it might confuse the citation tracker that takes care of the 'ibid' mechanism. But since 'ibid.' is highly ambiguous after such a citation anyway, a `\citereset` might be a good idea. (`\postnotedelim ;` seems like overkill.) I'd use `\citeauthor{sigfridsson}~\mkbibparens{\citeyear[159]{sigfridsson}; \cite[\textit{contra}][]{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}}`

Comment: Oh sorry, better use `\cite*{foo}` instead of `\citeyear{foo}`. This should work with all standard `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-like styles.

Comment: @moewe No that's not it, and yes that's precisely what I mean. In the following ( imgur.com/a/de8kf ), the first line is copied and modified from your comment, the second is copied and modified from the other post. This gives different results and it's the same with \cite*{foo} and persists when I recompile after deleting all but .bib and .tex files: imgur.com/a/8tJdD

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a difference between the two lines. And it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem! I don't see one either, but they produce different results as you can see in the second image. I'm curious to know why.

Comment: Sometimes during copy-and-pasting you can inadvertently copy an invisible character (it happens in the comments from time to time), maybe that is what happened here. But frankly there is not a lot we can say here, if the code looks the same it should do the same. Can you copy and paste both lines into your question? Anyway, would you say your question is a duplicate, or do you want an answer?

Comment: There seem to be some invisible characters between the g and e in `g‌​e` from `String‌​er1993` in your `\cite*` argument in the first line. I could see this when I deleted the `e` with backspace, I had to press backspace another two times to delete the `g` even though there was apparently nothing in between the two letters.